# Повторный вызов метода в приложении если ошибка

Tags: c#, windows-service, служба

Есть служба, которая раз в сутки делает запись в БД, данные для записи получает из парсинга сайта. Обнаружил случаи, что иногда в момент получения и записи, на конечной машине, где крутится служба, нет интернета. В приложение возникает исключение и в настройках службы стоит повторить через 10 минут, но этого не происходит. В связи с этим я хочу прикрутить к службе таймер и делать повторный запрос внутри службы. Опыта у меня мало, по этому вопрос, корректно ли будет все это сделать в `catch` где в `try` происходит попытка спарсить данные или это будет не правильно?

Comment: Судя по ваши описаниям - можно сделать try-catch в цикле (можно конечном, можно в бесконечном), и пытаться добиться результата пока исключение не пропадёт. Однако, многие осуждают практику циклов. Из вашего описания - лично я не вижу проблем использовать конечное число попыток через try-catch.

Comment: Перед запуском процесса парсинга разве не делается проверка на доступность соединения с сайтом? Это же так очевидно, сначала проверить доступность сайта, а потом уже выполнять парсинг и запись в БД, но в случае отсутствия соединения с сайтом пропускать этап парсинга  и возобновлять проверку соединения через какой-то промежуток времени.

Comment: @Bulson рекурсией?

Comment: Рекурсией нельзя, так вы забъете память в случае неудачных запросов к сайту.

Answer (score 0):

Для проверки возможности работы с сайтом можно воспользоваться таким классом

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class InternetAvailability
    {
       [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
       private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int description, int reservedValue);

        /// <summary>
        /// Проверка доступности Интернет
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsInternetAvailable()
        {
            int description;
            return InternetGetConnectedState(out description, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

В методе, который запрашивает сайт добавьте в начало проверку

```
//проверим доступность Интернета
if (!InternetAvailability.IsInternetAvailable())
{
    //здесь нужно сделать запись в лог или в БД
    //о том, что в такое-то время не было соединения с Интернетом
    return; //выходим из метода
}

//далее остальное по работе с сайтом
```

Таким образом вместо получения исключений можно просто фиксировать отсутствие связи.

Comment: А как повторить попытку через определенное время? Таймер повесить?

Comment: @Winteriscoming у вас же написано: "...в настройках службы стоит повторить через 10 минут...", я так понял у вас уже реализован режим повторения через равные промежутки времени.

Comment: В настройках службы есть пункт повторить в случае ошибки, вот там стоит раз в 10 минут пробовать, но оно почему то не отрабатывает.